# How to read content of files in directory using java and return the files which have particular keyword

Tags: java, java-8

In my code, I am able to list all the files from the folder on my pc but to check whether the keyword is present in those files I used indexOf() in StringBuffer. The problem I am facing is that desired output of filenames having that keyword is not getting printed.
I am not able to find where the error is or what mistake I am making.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListOfFiles {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // Creating a File object for directory
        File directoryPath = new File("C:\\Users\\nanis\\Downloads\\New folder");
        // List of all files and directories
        File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles();
        // System.out.println("List of files and directories in the specified directory:");
        Scanner sc = null;
        
        for (File file: filesList) {
            // System.out.println("File name: "+file.getName());
            // System.out.println("File path: "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            // System.out.println("Size :"+file.getTotalSpace());
            // Instantiating the Scanner class
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            String input;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                input = sc.nextLine();
                sb.append(input + " ");

                int integer = sb.indexOf("VM"); // the keyword is "VM" that I want to search
                if (integer > 0) {
                    System.out.println("keyword is present in " + file.getAbsolutePath())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There’s no sense in appending all lines to a `StringBuffer` and *repeatedly* searching the entire buffer for the keyword. Just search the particular line (`input`) right after it has been read. Further, the keyword might be at the beginning of the line, so you should use `>= 0` for the index. Or just use `if(input.contains("VM")) …` in the first place. And you should use the Scanner in a [`try(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your scanner. You are taking user input `input = sc.nextLine();` and to do that you need `System.in`. Also if I try to print something using `sc` it prints nothing and that would make `while (sc.hasNextLine())` false therefore there is something wrong with your algorithm.

You are doing a search algorithm right? but you are inserting the while loop inside the for each loop. This doesn't work because in the first iteration of the `for each` loop only the first file is present and so if your *search keyword* is for the last file it will be false.

A basic search algorithm would be:

```
1. Input keyword to find
2. Loop through the lists to check if found
3. return either true or false
```

EDIT: You want to search the .txt files. It is the same concept. You need to store them all first. Not search while storing. If you have stored them you can now search them.

I changed the code to read txt files. Also your directory should only contain `.txt` files otherwise it will not work because you are reading the content of the files. In your case HashMap would be useful because you need to store two values. File name and the content of it.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListOfFiles {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        // Creating a File object for directory
        File directoryPath = new File("C:\\Users\\nanis\\Downloads\\New folder\\");
        // List of all files and directories
        File filesList[] = directoryPath.listFiles();
        // System.out.println("List of files and directories in the specified
        // directory:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner myReader = null;
        HashMap<String, String> fff = new HashMap<String, String>(); // storage for the file name and content

        for (File file : filesList) {
            File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\nanis\\Downloads\\New folder\\" + file.getName());
            myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            String read = "";
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                read += myReader.nextLine();
            }
            fff.put(file.getName(), read); // store file name and its contents
        }

        System.out.print("Search The File By Keyword:");
        String find = sc.nextLine();
        for (String i : fff.keySet()) {
            if (fff.get(i).contains(find)) { // check the contents if it contains the keyword u are search for
                File found = new File("C:\\Users\\nanis\\Downloads\\New folder\\" + i);
                System.out.println("keyword is present in " + found.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        sc.close();
        myReader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but my query was that if the keyword is present within the file content then it must print those file names. In your code keyword is been searched within the file name instead. But thanks for your effort.

Comment: Are you planning to read only .txt files?

Comment: Yes, I am planning to read the .txt, .docx, .pdf files present in my directory.

Comment: @xopy. I have edited my answer but this would only work on txt files. Reading docx and pdf will make it more complex. I suggest reading about other API's that will support that